# What properties make a valid CellID?

Tags: notebooks, options, cells, document-creation

The documentation for [CellID](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellID.html) only mentions that it will be a number. But what kind of number? Can it be a real number with a decimal? How about a negative number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like when we specify a positive non-integer value `n` for `CellID`, it will be set to `Floor[n]`:

```
ids = RandomReal[{0, 100000}, 10];
Do[NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  Cell["abc", "Output", CellTags -> {"CellID"}, CellID -> n]], {n, ids}]
obtainedIDs = CellID /. Options /@ NotebookRead[Cells[CellTags -> {"CellID"}]];
NotebookDelete[Cells[CellTags -> {"CellID"}]]
Floor[ids] == obtainedIDs
```

> ```
> True
> ```

When we set `CellID -> 0`, this option will be removed from the `Cell` expression. And when we set a negative value for `CellID`, we get some random positive number as its value:

```
Do[NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  Cell["abc", "Output", CellTags -> {"CellID"}, CellID -> -1]], {10}]
obtainedIDs = CellID /. Options /@ NotebookRead[Cells[CellTags -> {"CellID"}]]
NotebookDelete[Cells[CellTags -> {"CellID"}]]
```

> ```
> {884743649, 49256706, 529128870, 40064242, 141034421, 29022860, 313623791, 10535229, 115646396, 66370412}
> ```

Any non-numerical values for `CellID` are simply ignored (equivalent to `0`).

**Hence a valid value for `CellID` is a positive integer number.** The value `0` is the default and means the absence of a value.

Comment: That is a great analysis. Legendary SE Mathematica user Kuba may have competition. lol